# Python-Selenium:How can I scrape some specific elements in the table and transform it from fractional to decimal

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, datatable

Here are some of the code of the page source:

```
<thead>
<tr>
<td rowspan="3">Order</td>
<td rowspan="3">Runner No.</td>
<td rowspan="3">Name</td>
<td colspan="6">Running Position &amp; Margin Behind Leader</td>
<td rowspan="3">Time</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="6">Sectional Time</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1st Sec.</td>
<td>2nd Sec.</td>
<td>3rd Sec.</td>
<td>4th Sec.</td>
<td>5th Sec.</td>
<td>6th Sec.</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1 </td>
<td>4</td>
<td style="white-space: nowrap; padding-right: 15px;"><a href="/xxxx.com" target="_blank">Jason</a></td>
<td>
<p class="f_clear"><span class="f_fl">2</span><i>1/2</i></p>
<p>12.87</p>
</td>
<td>
<p class="f_clear"><span class="f_fl">2</span><i>1/2</i></p>
<p>21.73</p>
</td>
<td>
<p class="f_clear"><span class="f_fl">1</span><i>2</i></p>
<p>22.77</p>
</td>

<td>0:57.37</td>
</tr>
<tr>
... #some more codes below as there are more than 1 runner
```

and what I need is

```
<tr>
<td>1 </td>
<td>4</td>
<td style="white-space: nowrap; padding-right: 15px;"><a href="/xxxx.com" target="_blank">Jason</a></td>
<td>
<p class="f_clear"><span class="f_fl">2</span><i>1/2</i></p>
<p>12.87</p>
</td>
<td>
<p class="f_clear"><span class="f_fl">2</span><i>1/2</i></p>
<p>21.73</p>
</td>
<td>
<p class="f_clear"><span class="f_fl">1</span><i>2</i></p>
<p>22.77</p>
</td>

<td>0:57.37</td>
</tr>
```

and because as you can see that some codes are like

`<p class="f_clear"><span class="f_fl">2</span><i>1/2</i></p>`

so when I use

```
sect_time = soup2.select('.table_bd.f_tac.race_table')
test3 = sect_time[0].find_all("tbody", attrs={'class': None})
testrow = []
for j in test3[0]('td'):
    testrow.append(j.getText())
```

and the result will be like

```
'1 ',
 '4',
 'Jason',
 ' 21/2 12.87 ',
 ' 21/2 21.73 ',
 ' 12 22.77 ',
 '  ',
 '  ',
 '  ',
 '0:57.37',
```

first is that the list cant split the elements, and second is it actually combined the number, such as

```
' 21/2 12.87 ',
 ' 21/2 21.73 ',
 ' 12 22.77 ',
```

the data should be like

```
'2','1/2','12.87','2','1/2','21.73','1','2','22.77'
```

so how can I split those elements to what I want and make the '1/2' to be '0.5'.

and one more question, since there are some runner information on another page, I have alr scraped those data, how could I match the above data to my previous data, FYI, the `order,runner no,name` are the same as the runner information page.

thank you very much if any one can provide some solutions/insight!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the issue of elements text being combined (i.e. `21/2 12.87` instead of `2, 1/2, 12.87`) by simply getting the tbody element that contains the items you want and then grabbing all the strings via `element.strings`

This will also contain bad strings that you don't care about/want (i.e. `'\n'`, `' '`, etc) so you will have to filter those values based on whether or not they are a number or resolve to a number.  If the value is not a number (i.e. it has a `/`) you can attempt to convert it into one via the built in `eval()` function.

```py
# You may have to modify how you get the tbody element if you have multiple
# tbody elements in your page.
values = page.find('tbody').strings

filtered_values = []
for value in values:
    # Normalize value
    value = value.strip(' ')

    # If digit is a float or a just a normal number - OK
    if value.replace(".", "", 1).isdigit():
        filtered_values.append(value)

    # Digit has the backslash symbol, it may be a float
    elif '/' in value:
        try:
            # It will evaluate string (i.e. solve 1/2 = 0.5)
            converted_value = str(eval(value))
            filtered_values.append(converted_value)
        except:
            # Ignore the value if it does not produce a number 
            # (i.e. cases where it has a '/' but also other non-numerical chars)
            continue 

print(filtered_values)
```

Comment: thank you for your solutions, it works, 
and can you also teach me the second question, how can I match these data to the previous information I have?

Comment: thx for the solutions
and can you also teach me the second question, how can I match these data to the previous information I have?

FYI, the previous list is 
```list2[0] = ['1', '4', 'JASON', 'T361', 'ZAC', 'ANDY', '120', '1085', '3', '2-1/2', '4', '7', '3', '0:57.80', '4.7']```

and because I reranged ```filtered_values``` 

now ```filtered_values[0] = [['1', '4', '2', '0.5', '12.87', '2', '0.5', '21.73', '1', '2', '22.77'],```

so the two "1" & "4" is representing the same runner in that field. but how can I combined it and I dont need double "1" & "4" . thx

Comment: Moreover, the eval() function seems not accurate, such as it transform "5-1/4" to  "4.75"
Anyway to correct it ? thx

Comment: for the above question
I mean "5-1/4" is actually = 5.25, the - isnt minus,